# update/refresh gid at runtime for a process

Tags: unix, process

Is there any possibility to "refresh" the gid information of a running process in Unix ? If the gid has been updated with a new user, is it possible to make the process running under that gid aware of the change, without restarting the process ?

Answer (score 1):

No it's not. The uid/gid are read when the process starts and the process will keep this same information. If the user/group permissions change along the way, the process will ie. run into issues when trying to write to the filesystem.

Only way to update the gid is to restart the process.